Using JPEG XL overlays
According to JPEG XL spec

Zero-duration frames are possible and represent different layers of the image.

Is this featured supported on GIMP or Inkscape or even a commandline tool like imagemagick?
E.g usage: how can I list all layers within a jxl file? How do I merge separate images 1.jxl, 2.jxl, ... into layer1 layer2, ... of out.jxl
Relevant question: Using avif overlays
